# Quit application on Ctrl+C in Quickly framework

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, gtk3

I found that when I run my application using "quickly run" and press Ctrl+c to kill it, the application does not quit. I am using Quickly 12.04.

For GTK2 applications, I used

```
def gtk_main_quit(self,widget,data=None):
    gtk.main_quit()
```

Is that enough to do it here with GTK3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the bugreport describing your issue: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=622084

Comment: is this an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> work as excepted and quit the application.
Insert this in your launcher script (PROJECT_ROOT/bin/yourapp)

```python
import signal
# ... 
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
# ... 
Gtk.main()
```

I've applied this method on my Python + Gtk3 project and haven't had any issue with it.